# calculate frequency of visits for a web page without storing every visit

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to calculate the frequency of visits for a web page, I'm using ExpressJS, mongoDB. I thought of storing every visit date and calculate the average of the difference between dates but this will lead to have a huge amount of dates data in the DB

I need to show on the frontend something like that:

- Frequency Visit: every 2 minutes
- Frequency Visit: every 2 days
- Frequency Visit: every 5 months

How can I do that without storing every visit date? please advise.

Comment: It depends... If I visited your website for the last time 1 year ago, and today I visit it twice in a 2 minute interval. Is my frequency "every 2 minutes"? If a frequency is based on X visits, you should be able to only store those X visits and periodically clear the remaining ones - via a cron job which runs every night, for example

Comment: @blex if you visited the website for the last time 1 year ago and then you visit it today, logically it should say "every year", is there a way to do it without storing visit dates ?